# Many contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, contenteditable

I have got a table that looks like this:

```
<table id="guests" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="guest1Name">John</td>
      <td id="guest1Relationship">Family</td>
      <td id="guest1NumberInParty">1</td>
      <td id="guest1InvitationSent">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="guest2Name">Joe</td>
      <td id="guest2Relationship">Family</td>
      <td id="guest2NumberInParty">1</td>
      <td id="guest2InvitationSent">No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This table will very quickly have over 100 rows. What I want to do is give each `<td>` the contenteditable attribute and watch for changes to each using JavaScript/jQuery so that when an element is done being edited the new data **for that one element** can be sent to the database using AJAX (the AJAX and server-side portion is already done). I want to do this using an `onblur` event or something similar, but I don't know how to watch all of those elements (100 rows x 4 elements each = 400+ elements) for focus/blur and be able to determine which one made the change. If I select them all using the jQuery `attributeStartsWith` selector, I can watch all of them, but when one of them loses focus, how do I know which one it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this. first assign a class to your editable TD's so selecting is easier. lets say class="editable".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editable').blur(function(e){
        //to get something from the li that was just blurred use this
        //something like - 
        var value = $(this).text();
        //Ajax call 
    });
});
```

using the this keyword inside of the event function will allow you to target the element the event was fired on.

Comment: Why would he need to assign a class?  Are there any `td` which are not editable?

Comment: he doesnt HAVE to i just suggested it to keep things simple. Of course he could just 
    $('td').hover(function(){});
but if in the future he ever has a reason to have non-editable ones on his page then he must retroactively change this. Do it right the first time no?
OP also doesnt specify whether he does or does not have non-editable td's.

Comment: Couldn't I do something like `$("[contenteditable='true']")` and not have to worry about any non-editable td's?

Comment: @Christopher Yes.  See also [classitis](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/web_development_mistakes/).

Comment: you can indeed do that. i was just giving a suggestion. regardless of whether you choose to use a class or not what I wrote AFTER that is the answer to your question.

Comment: @robertc the link you posted may have useful information but at its core it is still just an opinion of some blogger who thinks he knows better than everyone. Using spans, divs, and classes is not something to be overlooked particularly when trying to support older browsers. for example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp headers are not supported in anything below ie9. Nothing worse than a condescending comment to tell you that you're wrong based on opinion. I thought this was stackoverflow not reddit...

Comment: @iAmClownShoe I have been trying to get this working but have been unsuccessful. I have got `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".editable").blur(function(e) {
    var editedvalue = $(this).val();
    alert(editedvalue);
  });
});` and when one of the edited td's loses focus I do get an alert, but it's blank.

Comment: You can see my attempt at getting this to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Christopher/zsLUw/

Comment: i tried your fiddle and im getting the alert upon leaving the editable field. The editable field is the actual name field on each row as you have it set up. Those two fields are the only editable ones. The change to make this work to populate the alert is simple and i have updated my answer with it. change .val() to .text()

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your help.